# What's the non parameteric equation for the non-tilted version of this hyperbola

Tags: conic-sections

I'm trying to derive the standard non-tilted and non parametric version of this $45^\circ$ tilted hyperbola but the lack of square terms is throwing me for a loop.

$x - xy + y  + 5 = 0$

Can anyone walk me through the process?

Comment: You mean you want it on the form $y=f(x)$? Or do you want to turn it $45^\circ$, then express it on the form $\frac{(x-a)^2}{b}-\frac{(y-c)^2}{d}=1$? Or is there some other form you want to have it in?

Comment: I was looking for $\frac{(x - h)^2}{a^2} - \frac{(y -k)^2}{b^2} = 1$  after it was rotated back 45 degrees.

Comment: If you’ve performed the rotation correctly, you should end up with squared terms.

Answer (score 0):

Hint...if you rearrange it as $$y=\frac{x+5}{x-1}$$ you can see that the horizontal and vertical asymptotes intersect at $(1,1)$ so you need to rotate by $45^o$ about this point, not the origin.